# Old SQL to the New. table by table joins

Tags: oracle

With our oracle Database/queries that are currently running i have come across some SQL where they have done a table by table join. Now I want to be able to understand this so could someone explain? I am a newbie to this.

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM ra_customer_trx_all 
 WHERE customer_trx_id IN
(SELECT customer_trx_id 
FROM AR_PAYMENT_SCHEDULES_ALL
WHERE payment_schedule_ID IN
(SELECT payment_schedule_ID 
FROM AR_RECEIVABLE_APPLICATIONS_ALL
WHERE applied_customer_trx_id = 
SELECT customer_trx_id FROM ra_customer_trx_all WHERE trx_number = '34054'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st:
 select all TRX records from table ra_customer_trx_all where number = 34054
 we are looking for customer_trx_id

```
select * from ra_customer_trx_all t4 where t4.trx_number = '34054'
```

2nd: select all records from payment_schedule table that have the IDs from step1

```
select * from AR_RECEIVABLE_APPLICATIONS_ALL t3 where t3.payment_schedule_ID = (prev select)
```

3rd: select all records from customer_trx_all table that have the IDs from step2

```
select * from AR_PAYMENT_SCHEDULES_ALL t2 where t3.customer_trx_id = (prev select)
```

4th

```
select * from ra_customer_trx_all t1 where t2.customer_trx_id = (prev select)
```

5:
summary:

if *trx* is *transation*
the logic is:

*select all customer transaction records that have been scheduled to be paid via the RECEIVABLE_APPLICATIONS and transaction number is 34054*

```
SELECT t1.* 
 FROM ra_customer_trx_all t1
   inner join AR_PAYMENT_SCHEDULES_ALL t2 on t2.customer_trx_id = t1.customer_trx_id 
   inner join AR_RECEIVABLE_APPLICATIONS_ALL t3 on t3.payment_schedule_ID = t2.payment_schedule_ID
   inner join ra_customer_trx_all t4 on t4.customer_trx_id = t3.applied_customer_trx_id
 where t4.trx_number = '34054'
```

Comment: Could you put this into a query pls?

Comment: I added query via joins... but old syntax does absolutely the same

Comment: Thank you. I understand that the query already works. However I am more familarised with the new type.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace

```
select *
  from tableA
 where columnA in (select columnB 
                     from tableB
                    where columnB1 in (select ...))
```

with

```
select *
  from tableA, tableB
 where tableA.columnA = tableB.columnB
   and tableB.columnB1 in (select ...)
```

Apply this pattern sequentially to each subquery.
Short explanation: you open outer brackets after `IN` keyword, move table from inner `FROM` clause to outer, and add condition to `WHERE` clause: column before `IN` have to be equal to column in `SELECT` clause in subquery.

Comment: and how would i deal with the in clause within the brackets?

Comment: @Daniel Sorry, I thought it was obvious. I updated my post.

Comment: Be careful; if there are multiple rows in tableB for `tableA.columna = tableB.columnb and ...`, then you're going to end up with duplicate rows in the second query that you wouldn't in the first.